# useradd not working for user despite having changed /etc/sudoers

Tags: linux, sudoers

I added a user to `etc/sudoers` with `visudo` with the goal that that user could add another user on a Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS system.

This is the line I added:
`hf99 ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/sbin/userdel, /usr/bin/passwd`

Issue is that if I now try to add another user as `hf99` with `useradd foo`, I am prompted with

```
useradd: Permission denied.
userado: cannot lock /etc/passwo: try again later.
```

It does work with `sudo useradd foo`, so there is no `*.lock` file responsible for this not working.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure in the line you paste `h199 ALL=/usr/sbin/userado, /usr/sbin/userdel, /usr/bin/passwd`? I see **`/usr/sbin/userado`** (with `o` instead of `d`)

Comment: Likewise, `h199` or `hf99`? You can't define a `sudo` for one and expect it to work for the other. A typo in the question, perhaps? Or in reality? Please [fix your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1805943/edit) appropriately.

Comment: These are typos indeed, thanks for calling those out and sorry for my sloppiness...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding user to `/etc/sudoers` mean you will get these privileges when you execute commands with `sudo`:

```
sudo useradd foo
```

And will not get the elevated privileges when you exec just:

```
useradd foo
```

Comment: Wow, that's so obvious… Thanks for making that clear to me, of course it works now...